# How to access sleep monitor Data on Samsung Gear S3?

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, wearables

I would like to use the [humanactivitymonitor](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html#HumanActivityRecorderType) in order to access or record the sleepmonitor data which should previously have been recorded by sHealth. Although in the docs it says it is available since Tizen 2.3, I am getting the Error "Not supported type was passed" everytime I try to use the function `tizen.humanactivitymonitor.startRecorder('SLEEP_MONITOR');` or `tizen.humanactivitymonitor.readRecorderData('SLEEP_MONITOR',query, sleepStateChangedCB,onSleepError);`.

By the way: using the function `tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start('SLEEP_MONITOR', sleepStateChangedCB, sleepStateChangedErrorCB );` works perfectly fine but is not what i need.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? My Gear S3 is running on Tizen 2.3.2.3

Comment: Check out if human activity recorder type is supported.

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I switched to Tizen 3.0 instead

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
function startRecording() {

    var type = 'SLEEP_MONITOR';

    var options = {
        retentionPeriod : 1
    };

    try {
        tizen.humanactivitymonitor.startRecorder(type, options);
    } catch (err) {
        var message = 'cannot start recording' + err.name + ': ' + err.message
        console.log(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works well in Tizen 3.0 but not in Tizen 2.3. But thanks anyway.